# strcpy_P increases IROM usage by 400%

Tags: progmem

Using ESP8266 (NodeMcu 1) in Arduino IDE:

I can't upload my sketch because a single call to **strcpy_P** seems to increase the IROM usage by about 400%: 25% total usage without the call, 100+% with the call.

And even more strange, it depends on the second parameter of strcpy_P (the source):
If a pointer to a char array is provided, the usage increases dramatically

```
  char * ptr = (char *) pgm_read_word (&myArrays[index]);
  char buffer [1500];

  strcpy_P (buffer, ptr); // can't upload, uses 100+% of available IROM
```

Whereas with PSTR as parameter (just to test) total size of sketch is just 25% of IROM, leaving everything else unchanged:

```
  char * ptr = (char *) pgm_read_word (&myArrays[index]);
  char buffer [1500];

  strcpy_P(buffer, PSTR("Test")); // Ok, does not increase sketch size /IROM  usage
```

What's going on here ?

Comment: When its not used it willbe optimized out by the compiler.

Comment: what is `char * ptr = (char *) pgm_read_word (&myArrays[index]);`? you read address from flash?

Comment: I try to dynamically access  (by index) char arrays stored in PROGMEM. and these are referenced in  `const char* const myArrays[] PROGMEM = { arr1, arr2, arr3}`

Comment: @chrisl:  No, I commented out all referenecs to "buffer" after that call and still it uses 100% of IROM

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean, that it would be optimized out completely. The effect just sound very like optimization. Though I'm not an expert for the optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is not the `strcpy_P` function, but your array. Without that function call, the entire array can be removed by the compiler (I presume it's not used anywhere else). As soon as you add code that definitely accesses it, it is included in the code and therefore increases the size of the program so much.